# How to include multiple folder in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm trying to include multiple folders in JavaScript, specific: Discord JS, here's my code:

```
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./aPublic').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js')); // I wanted to include it here

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./aPublic/${file}`); // I wanted to include it here too!
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

I've tried to use `./aPublic && ./bAdmin` and also `('./aPublic') && ('./bAdmin')` but it only read the "bAdmin" folder rather than both of them, I wanted to include like 7 folders in both code.

Comment: Have you tried `path.join(__dirname, './aPublic/')` for readdirSync path? `const path = require("path");`

Comment: path.join(__dirname, './aPublic/' && './bAadmin) like that? what about the const command? i'm new to JS so yea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's put your list of directories in an array like below, use `.map()` to read each of them, join the path of each file with its corresponding directory and flatten the result using `.flat()`.

```js
const arrDir = ['./aPublic', './bPublic'];

const commandFiles = arrDir
    .map(dir => {
        const listFiles = fs.readdirSync(dir);
        return listFiles.map(file => path.join(__dirname, dir, file));
    })
    .flat()
    .filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(file);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

Comment: @Zhxck I have some errors in the for loop above. Give me a few seconds to correct them.

Comment: Edit : Ok i will

Comment: I've just updated the code. Basically we need to join the path first before filtering them.